# How do I make this JS function asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function takesTime(){

    for (var i = 0; i<some_very_large_number; i++){
        //do something synchronous
    }
    console.log('a');
}

takesTime();
console.log('b');
```

This prints:
a
b
How would you make it print:
b
a

Comment: sorry didn't realize there was such a thing!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I see this is tagged node.js, so I'll answer it from that perspective: you shouldn't. Usually, if you're blocking, it will be: network-bound (you should be using and/or reusing [network libraries](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/net.html) around asynchronous methods), I/O-bound (you should be using and/or reusing [I/O libraries](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/fs.html)), or CPU-bound. You haven't provided any context for what the long-running task is, and given that you have a loop invariant containing `some_very_large_number`, I'm assuming you're imagining some CPU-intensive task iterating over a large field.

If you're actually CPU-bound, you should rethink your strategy. Node only lives on one core, so even if you were able to use multithreading, you'd really just be spinning your wheels, as each request would still require a certain amount of CPU time. If you actually intend on doing something computationally-intensive, you may want to look into using a [queuing system](http://search.npmjs.org/#/redis-queue), and having something else processing the data that's better designed for crunching it.

Comment: Very nice job finding the deeper question under the question :)

Answer (score 20):

```
for (var i = 0; i < someVeryLargeNumber; ++i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        //do something synchronous
    }, 0);
}
```

Also see [setZeroTimeout](http://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts) to gain a few milliseconds each loop, although the work people are doing there seems to be browser-based.

Comment: So this is how all async functions in node (the non C libs) are implemented under the hood?

Comment: It's hard for me to say; I haven't looked at the Node source code myself, and I don't know what example functions you're referring to. Someone else might be able to answer better.

Comment: In node.js, you should use process.nextTick(function), not setTimeout(function, 0) -- it's more efficient.

Comment: Take a look at [setImmediate](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg) in newer versions of node.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is event-based, and everything happens in a single thread. The way for you to make it "asynchronous" is to use a timeout (setTimeout()).

Comment: Why is "asynchronous" in quotes? Asynchronous is not the same as multi-threaded; this isn't "fake" asynchronicity.

Comment: No, but asynchronous means not waiting for an action to finish before moving on. Javascript won't do that. When other languages do this, a concurrency mechanism is in use (e.g. seperate thread/process/DMA transfer/interrupt routine).

Comment: A blanket statement like that is sure to be false. C# for example does not use a concurrency mechanism (and in C# 5 such async is baked into the language). Indeed any language that allows callbacks can implement single-threaded asynchronicity.

Comment: And JavaScript will do that; an Ajax call (on the web) or an IO operation (in Node.js) is a great example of how JavaScript will not wait for the action to finish before moving on.

Comment: I"m not sure how you brought C# into this, but .NET has had async IO for a very, very long time (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.71).aspx 1.1, circa 2003). I'm assuming from the quotes here, and from the "not multi-threaded" answers, these people are taking him to mean he wants to perform some computationally-intensive task, which is not aided in the same way that IO is in node.

Comment: @Marc Bollinger: indeed, that's why I said C# doesn't use a concurrency mechanism. My point was that in C# 5 it's baked into the language, but async via callbacks has been there since the beginning, as you said. It got brought into this as a counter to @Phil Lello's blanket statement that other languages do asynchronicity via a concurrency mechanism.

Comment: Concurrency is in use; it just isn't in user code. I didn't go into details of what layer (user code vs language runtime vs libraries vs kernel) as it's not hugely relevant. I deliberately didn't say the language implemented it, I said it was in use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web workers to achieve your objective, but you'll require a separate js file, and you'll have to add plumbing code to post messages and handle those messages.

node.js doesn't support web workers natively, but an implementation is available at:

https://github.com/cramforce/node-worker/

Otherwise, it's similar to the following code:

```
var pid = require('child_process').spawn('node', ['childScript.js'])
pid.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
console.log('b');
```

## childScript.js

```
for (var i = 0; i < some_very_large_number; i++) {
  // do something synchronous
}
console.log('a');
```

Comment: One caveat: Not all browsers support workers; as the OP hasn't specified a specific browser, it's best to assume cross-browser support is important. Notably IE doesn't support workers yet (but may in IE9)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I should have prefixed it with the fact that this is node.js specific.